# Excel pass url with parameters to browser

Tags: html, excel

How is it possible to open local HTML file passing parameters from Excel sheet? It seems that passing the parameters works just for URL not for the file protocol.

does not work:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///C:/temp/html/new2017.htm?test=123","Search")
```

works:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://localhost/html/new2017.htm?test=123","Search")
```

What would be a way around it?

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: the file is opened without parameters.